# Struts Migration tools

Tags: struts2

Are there any migration/coversion tools available to convert the old files from Struts 1.x to 2.x version.

I have tried over the google but couldn't find as we are currently in the process of migrating and due to large number of files.

Thanks in advance

Murthy

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: @murthy I don't remember if such tool ever existed asking us to find it is off-topic on SO, and you must know that.

Comment: @RomanC, yes i agree, but i'm little curious as many have them gone through it and if there is any utility of such kind implemented and wanted to know about it. not to offend someone. 

This is because Struts documentation says conversion wizards in this link https://struts.apache.org/docs/migration-tools.html. And if someone has known it or implemneted it which can be beneficial

Comment: Even if it existed, a migration tool like that would be counterproductive; the two frameworks are very different, and so are the patterns used, that in S2 are newer and more easy/robust/clean. S1 is dead a long time ago (I mean *officially* dead, because it is *virtually* dead since when Struts2 is born, a decade ago). IF your company founds itself in the need of converting / evoluting / migrating S1 applications to S2 in 2017, then the best shot is to learn how to do it properly, from scratch, with the latest S2, keeping only the (needed) domain logic from the old webapp, and zero code

Comment: And +1 for your politeness against unneeded downvotes